# Calling VB function from VBscript

Tags: vbscript

wsdl tool coverts a wsdl file which is a xml file into specified language file. wsdl describes a web service. i want to consume a web service. so using its wsdl file i ve generated a vb file( i specified vb as option while generating this using wsdl tool). How can I call methods of this file from vbscript.

Comment: Just because I don't know, what is a .VB file and what is WSDL? Can you tell me more about the stub file? I assume it's written in VB.NET, but I'm not sure what WSDL is, and I'm not sure why it's a stub file. How do you expect to call methods from that file if it isn't compiled?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm still not sure (and it may be because I'm simply ignorant as to what you're talking about) how turning your WSDL file into a VB file *compiles* that code. It's not possible to call methods from a raw source file. It has to be compiled into a binary first (either an executable or a DLL).

Comment: ya generated the dll and registered the dll to registry. now i'm able to call the methods from vbscript. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Is it possible to execute a .NET assembly(dll) from vbscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600012/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-net-assemblydll-from-vbscript)

[How do I call .NET code (C#/vb.net) from vbScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357440/how-do-i-call-net-code-c-vb-net-from-vbscript)

[Access a custom .NET DLL in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345180/how-do-you-access-a-custom-net-dll-in-vbscript)

[calling .NET COM object from VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885038/calling-net-com-object-from-vbscript)

[Why is this C# COM class usable from VBScript but not JScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712005/why-is-this-c-com-class-usable-from-vbscript-but-not-jscript)